# Microsoft bot framework broke on its own

Tags: rest, api, bots, botframework, access-token

I am getting this for my token request:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS90002: No service namespace named 'botframework.com' was found in the data store.\r\nTrace ID: d164a5d4-2c28-4491-bd88-1f8b31b52800\r\nCorrelation ID: 3ab5127e-690e-40b6-a433-2986bd711541\r\nTimestamp: 2017-07-25 18:38:00Z",
    "error_codes": [90002],
    "timestamp": "2017-07-25 18:38:00Z",
    "trace_id": "d164a5d4-2c28-4491-bd88-1f8b31b52800",
    "correlation_id": "3ab5127e-690e-40b6-a433-2986bd711541"
}
```

Has the namespace changed? Can't figure out anywhere. It's also V3.1 so don't see why its not working?

I am sending request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: getting same error since last 20 mins. cant figure out, why

Comment: V3.0 is working. I have shifted to v3.0 for now. URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Change for this URL:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
And this scope:
https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Comment: I'm learning to integrate LUIS into my bot and I start seeing this too. But there is no V3 for `LuisVersion` in `LuisModel`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: The issue has been resolved and bots should be back to their normal activity. A rca with additional information is forthcoming.

Answer (score 6):

Its an issue from bot framework authentication portal.MS have acknowledged it and is working to get it fixed. see my issue report and their comment .

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3197

Answer (score 3):

The issue has now been resolved. Please let us know if you see this again.